# CSS grid dimensions

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like to know if there is a way to limit the dimensions of a grid (not the element to which it's applied, the grid itself). I explain :

Let's say we've got a footer, with a dark background, spanning all the width of your page.
This footer contains 2 sub-blocks, classnames .footer__1 and .footer__2, and we want them to occupy 2/3 and 1/3 of the available width, with a 2rem gutter.

Is there a way to give the grid containing the two sub-blocks a grid-max-width (yes, i made that up) of 60rem, without changing the block width (remember, it has a background which must be full width), without using a wrapper ?
So, the occupied width (.footer__1 + gap + .footer__2) should be 60rem max, centered horizontally.

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer__1">foo</div>
  <div class="footer__2">whatever</div>
</footer>
```

```
.footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template_columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  /* grid-max-width: 60rem */
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap it with an additional element and limit the width to the additional element.

```css
footer {
  background-image: linear-gradient(20deg, red, pink);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  
  /* just for demo purpose */
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: white;
  
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer__1">foo</div>
    <div class="footer__2">whatever</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without another container, I think it is not possible.

However, you can mimic it by making the footer `width: 60rem` and set the background as a pseudo-element and expand it.

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 9999px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer__1">foo</div>
  <div class="footer__2">whatever</div>
</footer>
```

The best approach, as I think, is to add `div.footer__inner` that will hold the two divs - `.footer__1` and `.footer__2`.